# PWA React Js apk output doesn't work correctly on Tinker Board

Tags: android, reactjs, android-studio, apk, progressive-web-apps

I have this project of mine based on react js and it's also PWA. I want to make an apk out of it with the android studio as a web view and it works fine on my android phone but has problems on Asus Tinker Board. It kinda gets broken...some of the CSS does not work well and the app goes black when it tries to get some data from the local storage and cookie to fetch data online. Does anyone have any idea regarding this problem of mine??

Comment: If it's already a PWA, you can use https://www.pwabuilder.com/ to wrap it up into an android bundle which might be a bit more robust. 

PWA Builder uses bubblewrap: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/bubblewrap under the hood for Android app generation, which you can run locally if you'd prefer to tinker

Comment: Thank you, I'll test it.

Comment: It turned out that some of the CSS I used was not supported by android 8 and everything worked perfectly on android 11. But the weird thing is it only didn't work as an APK and everything was fine when I opened it in a browser of the android 8.